# "the trait is not implemented for mutable generic type,' even though it appears to be so

Tags: unit-testing, rust, i2c

I've got this code which I've tried to distill to its most basic essence:

```
use std::error::Error;

pub trait I2CDevice {
    type Error: Error; 
}

struct MySensor<T: I2CDevice + Sized> {
    Device : T
}

impl<T> MySensor<T> where T: I2CDevice + Sized {
    pub fn new(dev: &mut T) {
        let cal = get_calibration(dev);
        let mut mySensor = &mut MySensor { Device: dev};
    }
}

fn get_calibration<T: I2CDevice + Sized>(dev: &mut T) -> Calibration {
    Calibration {}
}

struct Calibration {
}
```

but which fails to compile, with the error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&mut T: I2CDevice` is not satisfied  
--> src\main.rs:17:33    
| 17 |         let mut mySensor = &mut MySensor { Device: dev};    
|                                      ^^^^^^^^
the trait `I2CDevice` is not implemented for `&mut T`    
|    = note:required by `MySensor`
```

I feel like the type constraint I have used on the impl of `MySensor` adequately restricts `T` such that it should satisfy, well, that exact same constraint on the `MySensor` struct itself.  So I'm stuck.

The mutability has been forced on me by the requirements of the `I2CDevice` trait members.

To give a bit more background, I'm trying to write an abstraction around a particular I2C-based hardware sensor so that the sensor can be used without having to know the particulars of interacting with that sensor over the I2C network.

I am using the [rust-i2cdev crate](https://github.com/rust-embedded/rust-i2cdev/blob/master/src/linux.rs) which defines a `LinuxI2CDevice` struct which impls the `I2CDevice` trait, however my own code is a mess, so I am hoping to cover the code with tests prior to refactoring.  To do this I'm trying to replace the `LinuxI2CDevice` struct references with `I2CDevice` trait references, so that I can create test doubles which are also `I2CDevice` impls, which would then allow me to confidently clean up the messy code.

If I am attacking *that* overarching goal in the wrong way, I'd certainly appreciate being pointed toward better strategies.

Comment: [This works](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=5b80834b22da3381b56d255b90fafbdd&version=stable), but may be more restrictive than you were imagining. I'm not sure if it helps you or not. The key is in the error message. Specifically: `&mut T`. Your bound restricts `T` to `I2CDevice` but `&mut T !== T` in Rust. If you're going to store a reference you need to say you are... which of course includes the need for explicit lifetimes.

Comment: This seems to be an ideal solution, and the explanation is helpful too.  I'd gladly accept this if you were to paste this same content into a formal answer.